# Can I modify the global search?

Tags: global-search

My company is unhappy with the way global search works.  They want a search that provides alot more filtering on accounts. We've added a custom search with additional filters, but they don't like it.  They want this functionality to be provided from the global search.

Base question:  Can global search be modified through custom code?  I've always assumed no but I'm seeking confirmation.

Comment: Adding to @Mohith answer,  with VF, use SOSL for global search in controller side. It will return you objects and you have to manipulate according to your Ux requirement.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost its important to understand that in Aloha UI ,if you turn off the global search then you will have to turn off the chatter .This might be serious implication .

While You can always replicate the global search via visualforce and add as much as functionality you need ,its going to be lot of maintenance .

Looks like you need a better account search page which you can build using vf and add as a tab or link and Train the Users to use that for additional searching and filtering of account .

Answer (score 0):

To disable Global Search , You need to disable Chatter to disable Salesforce Global search.

Go to Setup -> chatter -> chatter setting -> Enable='Uncheck'

And use custom code for searching accounts